# Groupby id and timestap (timestamp threshold 45 minutes) in polars

Tags: python, group-by, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe with a 'col1' column and a 'col2' column.
Now I want to groupby the two columns and to create a new column. I have the following example data:

```
data1 = {
    "col1": [1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    "col2": [
        "2022-05-25T08:00:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T08:15:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T08:30:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T08:45:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T09:00:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T09:15:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T09:30:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T09:45:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T10:00:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T10:15:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T10:30:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T10:45:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T08:00:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T08:15:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T08:30:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T08:45:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T09:00:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T06:00:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T06:15:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T06:30:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T06:45:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T07:00:00.648681",
        "2022-05-25T07:15:00.648681",
    ],
}

# Create a DataFrame from the dictionary
test = pl.DataFrame(data1)
test = test.with_columns(pl.col("col2").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

Now I want to create column 'col3' where 'col1' and 'col2' are grouped by with a threshold of 45 minutes. Example if col1 = 1 and col2 = within a period of 45 minutes set the value of col3 as 1. if col1 = 1 and col2 = within the next period of 45 minutes set the value of col3 as 2

So the desired outcome should be as follows:

```
col1    col2                       col3
i64 datetime[ns]
1   2022-05-25 08:00:00.000648681  1
1   2022-05-25 08:15:00.000648681  1
1   2022-05-25 08:30:00.000648681  1
1   2022-05-25 08:45:00.000648681  1
1   2022-05-25 09:00:00.000648681  2
1   2022-05-25 09:15:00.000648681  2
1   2022-05-25 09:30:00.000648681  2
1   2022-05-25 09:45:00.000648681  2
1   2022-05-25 10:00:00.000648681  3
1   2022-05-25 10:15:00.000648681  3
1   2022-05-25 10:30:00.000648681  3
1   2022-05-25 10:45:00.000648681  3
2   2022-05-25 08:00:00.000648681  3
2   2022-05-25 08:15:00.000648681  3
2   2022-05-25 08:30:00.000648681  3
2   2022-05-25 08:45:00.000648681  3
2   2022-05-25 09:00:00.000648681  4
2   2022-05-25 06:00:00.000648681  1
2   2022-05-25 06:15:00.000648681  1
2   2022-05-25 06:30:00.000648681  1
2   2022-05-25 06:45:00.000648681  1
2   2022-05-25 07:00:00.000648681  2
2   2022-05-25 07:15:00.00064868   2
```

How would you do this in polars?

Comment: It should probably be `pl.Datetime` instead of `pl.Date` otherwise you're discarding the time information. What should the output be for your example data?

Comment: I have added the output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly.

From your desired outcome, it looks like column3 starts at 1 for the first hour of each day and each group. Then it increases by 1 for every hour.

If that is the case, you can reproduce it by calculating the rank of the hour, over the group and day.

```
test.with_columns(
    col3 = pl.col('col2').dt.hour().rank(method='dense')
        .over([pl.col('col1'),pl.col('col2').dt.truncate('1d')])
)

shape: (23, 3)
┌──────┬───────────────────────────────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2                          ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---                           ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ datetime[ns]                  ┆ u32  │
╞══════╪═══════════════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2022-05-25 08:00:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 1    ┆ 2022-05-25 08:15:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 1    ┆ 2022-05-25 08:30:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 1    ┆ 2022-05-25 08:45:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 1    ┆ 2022-05-25 09:00:00.000648681 ┆ 2    │
│ 1    ┆ 2022-05-25 09:15:00.000648681 ┆ 2    │
│ 1    ┆ 2022-05-25 09:30:00.000648681 ┆ 2    │
│ ...  ┆ ...                           ┆ ...  │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 08:45:00.000648681 ┆ 3    │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 09:00:00.000648681 ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 06:00:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 06:15:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 06:30:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 06:45:00.000648681 ┆ 1    │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 07:00:00.000648681 ┆ 2    │
│ 2    ┆ 2022-05-25 07:15:00.000648681 ┆ 2    │
└──────┴───────────────────────────────┴──────┘
```

For details on the code:
`pl.col('col2').dt.hour()` returns the hour of the day
`pl.col('col2').dt.truncate('1d')` returns the day
`.rank(method='dense').over()` calculates the rank over a certain perimeter. It's a window function.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?